# How to assign labels to nodes in boost?

Tags: c++

I know the no.of nodes of a graph. I want to assign labels the nodes of graph as A,B,C,D. If I have 5 nodes, label it as A,B,C,D,E. If I have 6 nodes, label it as A,B,C,D,E,F. Can you suggest any dynamic method for this?

```
  enum nodes { A, B, C, D, E };
  char name[] = "ABCDE";
```

Comment: Who's this "u" character?

Answer (score 1):

You question is not clear at all - I don't understand why you need boost or what you're trying to do. That said, let's assume that:

- You have an `enum` of node types `A`..`Z`.
- You need a way to convert the enum value to a string representation at run-time.

---

[gcc.godbolt.org example](https://godbolt.org/g/XFhJD7).

```
#include <cstddef>

// Use `enum class` for additional safety.
// Explictly specify the underyling type as we're going to use the
// enum values to access an array.
enum class nodes : std::size_t { A = 0, B, C, D, E, /* ... */ };

// `constexpr` allows this function to work both at run-time and 
// compile-time.
constexpr auto get_char_for(nodes n) noexcept
{
    // Represent the alphabet as a `constexpr` C-style string.
    constexpr const char* letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ"; 

    // Access and return the alphabet letter at position `n`.
    return letters[static_cast<std::size_t>(n)];
}

static_assert(get_char_for(nodes::A) == 'A');
```

Comment: how to store it in a vector name[]

Comment: @angel: there is no need to store it in an `std::vector`. If you really wated to, you could store the alphabet in a `std::vector<char>`, but that has no benefits whatsoever compared to a `const char*`. You seem to lack basic knowledge regarding the language - I advise reading a book like "C++ Primer 5th edition" or any of Bjarne's books to get a proper understanding of what's going on.

Comment: actually i need to store it in name